# An explanation about Sequence points

Tags: c++, sequence-points

Lately, I have seen a lot of questions being asked about output for some crazy yet syntactically allowed code statements like like `i = ++i + 1` and `i=(i,i++,i)+1;`.
Frankly realistically speaking hardly anyone writes any such code in actual programing.To be frank I have never encountered any such code in my professional experience. So I usually end up skipping such questions here on SO. But lately the sheer volume of such Q's being asked makes me think if I am missing out some important theory by skipping such Q's. I gather that the such Q's revolve around `Sequence points`. I hardly know anything about sequence points to be frank and I am just wondering if not knowing about it is a handicap in some way. So can someone please explain the theory /concept of `Sequence points`, or If possible point to a resource which explains about the concept. Also, is it worth to invest time in knowing about this concept/theory?

Comment: Steve Summit's article [here](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html) would be useful.

Comment: Read section 1.9, and the introduction to section 5 (i.e. before 5.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer I can think of is:

C++ is defined in terms of an abstract machine. The output of a program executed on the abstract machine is defined ONLY in terms of the order that "side effects" are performed. And Side effects are defined as calls into IO library functions, and changes to variables marked volatile.

C++ compilers are allowed to do whatever they want internally to optimize code, but they cannot change the order of writes to volatile variables, and io calls.

Sequence points define the c/c++ program's heartbeat - side effects before the sequence point are "complete" and side effects after the sequence point have not yet taken place. But, side effects (or, code that can effect a side effect indirectly( *within* a sequence point can be re-ordered.

Which is why understanding them is important. Without that understanding, your fundamental understanding of what a c++ program is (And how it might be optimized by an agressive compiler) is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point.

It's a quite simple concept, so you don't need to invest much time :)

Comment: I do not agree about it being a simple concept, from what i have seen in threads and explanations it seems to be quite a tough concept to grasp, Or perhaps, its just seems difficult to me!

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia article.  The first sentence basically defines the concept.  There are many details on where sequence occur in C++, but that's not about the concept.

Answer (score 2):

The exact technical details of sequence points can get hairy, yes.  But following these guideline solves almost all the practical issues:

- If an expression modifies a value, there must be a sequence point between the modification and *any* other use of that value.
- If you're not sure whether two uses of a value are separated by a sequence point or not, break up your code into more statements.

Here "modification" includes assignment operations on the left-hand value in `=`, `+=`, etc., and also the `++x`, `x++`, `--x`, and `x--` syntaxes.  (It's usually these increment/decrement expressions where some people try to be clever and end up getting into trouble.)

Luckily, there are sequence points in most of the "expected" places:

- At the end of every statement or declaration.
- At the beginning and end of every function call.
- At the built-in `&&` and `||` operators.
- At the `?` in a ternary expression.
- At the built-in `,` comma operator.  (Most commonly seen in for conditions, e.g. `for (a=0, b=0; a<m && b<n; ++a, ++b)`.)  A comma which separates function arguments is *not* the comma operator and is *not* a sequence point.

Overloaded `operator&&`, `operator||`, and `operator,` do not cause sequence points.  Potential surprises from that fact is one reason overloading them is usually discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth knowing that sequence points exist because if you don't know about them you can easily write code which seems to run fine in testing but actually is undefined and might fail when you run it on another computer or with different compile options. In particular if you write for example `x++` as part of a larger expression that also includes `x` you can easily run into problems.

I don't think it is necessary to learn all the rules fully - but you need to know when you need to check the specification, or perhaps better - when to rewrite your code to make it so that you aren't relying on sequence points rules if a simpler design would work too.

Comment: I know it is quite subjective to ask, but knowing how much is knowing enough? What are the rules that one MUST/ATLEAST know of?

Answer (score 0):

```
int n,n_squared;
for(n=n_squared=0;n<100;n_squared+=n+ ++n)
 printf("%i squared might or might not be %i\n",n,n_squared);
```

... doesn't always do what you think it will do. This can make debugging painful.
The reason is the ++n retrieves, modifies, and stores the value of n, which could be before or after n is retrieved. Therefore, the value of n_squared isn't clearly defined after the first iteration. Sequence points guarantee that the subexpressions are evaluated in order.